# What happens to the load when a bridge rectifier is in over-voltage condition?

Tags: surge-protection, bridge-rectifier

Please read carefully, this may or may not be trivial:

Your  bridge rectifier (Schottky diode based) is rated for 60 Volts Maximum Peak and the AC wave peaks at 65V for a short period of time.

What would happen to the transformer and what would the load see?

It seems to me that the reverse polarity diodes would act like two TVS diodes and "clamp" the source thereby somewhat protecting the load. Or would some other result occur?

(assume the silicon and packaging can dissipate the heat and temperature is not an issue).

Comment: Sounds like a smells like.... don't breathe this answer?

Comment: "Your Schottky bridge rectifier" - can't answer that, don't have one.

Comment: You're assuming that these diodes rated for 60 V **will show breakdown** at 65 V. This cannot be guaranteed ! They might break down at 100 V or 61.5 V. Also, you're using the diodes outside their specification so anything can happen, fail open, fail short, or no fail at all. And if the diodes would "clamp" what happens to them ? They will need to dissipate a lot of power in order to clamp the voltage (assuming the transformer can deliver that power) and they will break. It is impossible to be sure what will happen. Real engineers don't rely on that, they design so that this does not happen.

Comment: @FakeMoustache "they design so that this does not happen" In my world, over voltage is _always_ a possibility and "can't happen" happens. You just need to think about what happens after.  I honestly want to thank you for taking the time to give some kind of answer (others, I have choice words for).  If we can get back to the electronics: so **four possibilities?** : 1) no fail 2) breakdown 3) fail short 4) fail open.  wouldn't we have to look at a Wheatstone bridge look-alike for each case? (which means only the breakdown case is worth investigating?)

Comment: If an over-voltage can happen, you have to design an appropiate protection, so that it can't.